# check if array exist in object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say i have multiple object like this :

```
let obj1 = {
   a : 1,
   b:2,
   c:[{d:44,f:66}]
}

let obj2 = {
  q:100,
  w:400,
  s:900,
  rr:1
}
```

these two object are passed to a function, is there any way that i can detect there is/are array exist in object ?

for example :

```
const createData = (obj) => {    
  //if obj was obj2 continue but if obj was obj1 pass obj1.c to another function
}
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz i just updated it

Comment: please read the comment on createData function

Comment: i have no idea. please add some examples and the result, you expect.

Comment: @Enzo So you want to check if the passed object contains an array?

Comment: @nickzoum no need, i just need the value, the answer from Alopwer is correct

Comment: @Enzo Should the check be recursive?

Comment: btw, why the name `arr` for objects?

Comment: @nickzoum yes it should be recursive

Comment: @NinaScholz true, my bad, will fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method Array.isArray which makes this check

```
const createData = (obj) => {    
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if(Array.isArray(obj[prop]) {
        console.log(obj[prop])
    }
  }
}
```